# What is the connection between these two PDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Does anyone see a or know of some connection between solutions to the two Gross-Pitaevskii-Equations

> $i \partial_t \phi = \Delta \phi +\phi(1-|\phi|^2) ~~~~~~~~~~~ (1)$

and

> $i \partial_t \phi = \Delta \phi -\phi(1-|\phi|^2) ~~~~~~~~~~~ (2)$

Are there any known results as "If $\phi$ is a solution to (1) then ... is a solution to (2)". I can't seem to find any.

Our viewpoint is $\phi : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{C}$, $(t,x) \mapsto \phi(t,x)$.

Comment: Consider a simplified situation: stationary solution  ($\partial_t\phi = 0$), small $\phi$ (that is, $|\phi|^3$ is negligible). Then the equations are $\Delta \phi+ \phi = 0$  and $\Delta \phi - \phi = 0$, which are very different animals. The latter satisfies the maximum principle and has unique solution for any Dirichlet data. The former does neither.

Comment: Care to post this as an answer?